# Link to JQuery Tab from within page content

Tags: jquery

I'm building an application that is using JQuery to created tabbed content on the homepage.

I'm using this example of code to build on.
http://jqueryfordesigners.com/jquery-tabs/

This all works great however how can I link to a tab so that it acts the same as clicking the tabbed links from within any content on the homepage or site?

My Javascript code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var tabContainers = $('div.tabs > div');

$('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').click(function () {
    tabContainers.hide().filter(this.hash).show();

    $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    return false;
}).filter(':first').click();
```

});

My HTML.

```
    <div class="tabs">
  <!-- tabs -->
  <ul class="tabNavigation">
    <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab4">Tab 4</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- tab containers -->
  <div id="tab1">
    ...
  </div>
  <div id="tab2">
    ...
  </div>
  <div id="tab3">
    ...
  </div>
  <div id="tab4">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

I thought I could do something link

```
<a href="#tab3">My link text</a>
```

in my content but I'm assuming i need to make same addition to the javascript code to make this work.

**EDIT**
I'ved added the following code to my javascript however I the tab I clicked doesn't get the selected css rule.

```
    // add code for links to tabs
$('a.tablink').click(function (){

    tabContainers.hide().filter(this.hash).show();

    $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this.hash).addClass('selected');

    return false;
})
```

What do I need to change here
    $(this.hash).addClass('selected');
to add the css class .selected

Comment: Try using the CSS3 `:target` selector in your jQuery to identify the tab that was clicked.

Comment: I didn't know about this CSS3 selector and while it does work, it's selecting the information div and not the li a element menu item because that has the #id.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
tabContainers.filter(window.location.hash).show();
```

inside your ready function, perhaps? Then the link example.org/path#tab2 will open the correct tab on pageload.

EDIT: Oh, I think I misinterpreted the question a bit. Did you also want to be able to open a tab when your'e on the same page? Then you could use [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

```
<a href="#tab3" onclick="$('#tab3').trigger('click');">My link text</a>
```

*(Actually it's very ugly to write inline JavaScript, but it might be the easiest way if you are dealing with a CMS for example.)*

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will work for linking within the same page.

```
var currentHash = document.location.hash;
$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
    if(currentHash != document.location.hash){
        $("a[href*="+document.location.hash+"]").click();
        currentHash = document.location.hash;
    }
});
```

Then you can link to the tab via the hash like this:

```
<a href="#tab-hash-here">Link Title</a>
```