# Link to JQuery Tab from within page content with ajax tabs

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do this [Link to JQuery Tab from within page content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405904/link-to-jquery-tab-from-within-page-content)

But my pages are loaded from other pages like so

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="/account/honors.jsp">Honors</a></li>
    <li><a href="/account/history.jsp">History</a></li>
    <li><a href="/account/following.jsp">Following</a></li>
</ul>
```

How do I reference the ajax pages?

Comment: Found this question but the answer links to a broken page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469147/preload-tab-with-in-url-using-jquery-tabs-with-ajax?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I used, added this to my onload function.

```
function jumpToTab() {
    hashNum = window.location.hash.replace('\#','');
    $("#profileTabs").tabs('select',hashNum);
}

jumpToTab();    

$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
   jumpToTab();
});
```

Links look like

```
<a href="tabsPage">Tab One</a>
<a href="tabsPage#1">Tab Two</a>
<a href="tabsPage#2">Tab Three</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on this for the last two days, using various answers.  Many of the problems I've found are due to Answers referencing old versions of jqueryui.

The below works for jqueryui 1.12.1

I added the below code to the button click of a jqueryui modal

```
"Switch To Next Tab": function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );//Close the modal
            $('#modal1body').empty;//empty the div container form current modal
            $('#tabs .ui-tabs-active')//remove the active classes for all tabs
                .removeClass("ui-tabs-active")
                .removeClass("ui-state-active");
            $('#tabs').tabs({ active: 1});//Set new tab = current tab + 1
}
```